# chartjs-plugin-zoomのpanが正しく機能しないのはなぜでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, chart.js

#### 前提・実現したいこと

chartjs-plugin-zoomを使って以下のようなコードで、グラフを作りました。
https://codepen.io/nemurino-kai/pen/QWNexKJ?editors=0010
[image: グラフ]

[chartjs-plugin-zoomのgithub](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom)にある[Live Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/jledentu/pen/NWWZryv)を改変して作成しました。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

「グラフを左にスライドして、昔の期間を見ることはできるが、グラフを右にスライドできない」という、問題が生じています。

なぜ、この問題が起きているのでしょうか？
この問題を直すためには、どのようにコードを書き換えればよいのでしょうか？ご教授ください。

#### 補足情報

round: 'day'を消すと、問題は発生しなくなりました。しかし、私は、round: 'day' を設定しつつ、正常にpanを機能させたいです。

ChromeおよびFirefoxで、問題が発生するのを確認しました。